# Two USB barcode verifiers plugged into 1 computer, Need to swap between USB devices

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, barcode-scanner

I'm wrecking my brain trying to think how i could do this...

We have 2 Barcode verifiers that will verify two different barcodes on a particular box. This task will be preformed by our operations team. Issue/Problem I'm running into is that the software used doesn't support multiple USB devices plugged in at the same time. So the solution I thought of was a "USB Switch" of some kind but most switches are for USB devices to computers A or B but i need a switch to do the opposite.

Do you guys have any idea if such a product exists or is it even possible ?

Comment: Why do you have 2 different scanners?  My cell phone scanner can do approx 10 different barcodes.  Is there a reason you don't have 1 that can do both?

Comment: The reason there are two scanners is because they are used for Grading purposes. We are using a company called Cognex but there software doesn't support multiple devices

Comment: I have add an answer that require no pesky switches or other hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Get virtualization product like VMWARE workstation or Oracle virtual box.

Create 2 virtual machines.

1. barcode machine 1 and software
2. barcode machine 2 and software

OR

1. machine 1 on host
2. machine 2 on virtual machine

Go into the settings for the virtual machines and dedicate the barcode scanner to the correct virtual machine.

Once the virtual machine claims it neither the host or the other virtual machine will "see" it.

before:
[image]

[image: settings]

You may have to change the USB type to get it work.

start the VM.

Afterward:
[image: after]

Technically you could leave 1 attached to the host, and only use 1 virtual machine.  You would still be able use both at the same time because the VM is isolated from the host.

I needed **Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-6.0.4.vbox-extpack**  to get it to work with USB 2/3 speeds.

The **K:** is gone because the virtual machine owns it.

---

A lesser option is to go into the device manager and disable one device and enable the other.  Then reverse the process.

However, its a lot of switching back and forth.  When as an alternative you could use a virtual machine and just start and stop the virtual machine(s).